# Membership page php

Tags: php, authentication, membership

We are trying to create a membership login page.

This is my code.

**main_login**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
    <table style="width:300px;border:0;text-align:center;background-color:#CCCCCC">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="width:100%;background-color:#FFFFFF;border:0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:78px">Username</td>
                        <td style="width:6px">:</td>
                        <td style="width:294px"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td><input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**checkLogin.php**

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'myuse';
$dbpass = 'myPassword';
$dbname = 'myDbName';

// This is an example opendb.php
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die  ('Error connecting to mysql');
mysql_select_db($dbname);


// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"

$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
$_SESSION['mypassword']   = $mypassword;
$_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1; 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

**login_success.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!empty($_SESSION['Username']))  
  {  }
 else
  {header("location:main_login.php");}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
// Check if session is not registered , redirect back to main page. // Put this
code in first line of web page.
<html>
<body>
    Login Successful
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to make login_success.php only viewable for members only, but I only get redirected to main_login.php.

I don't think I am sending the Session to login_success.php

Can anybody help? please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the biggest (and only) problem could be, that while logging in, you set these keys in your $_SESSION array:

```
$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
$_SESSION['mypassword']   = $mypassword;
$_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;
```

but then you check for different one:

```
$_SESSION['Username']
```

Comment: Thank You, I cant believe I missed that out. Is that secure enough? Thanks.

Comment: security is always an interesting question. the php session is about all you've got for maintaining someone's logged in status.  one thing to note is that if your site is accessed via an insecure connection (non-ssl) the username / password is sent via plain text to the server. if an attacker is able to view that content (wireshark in starbucks, for example) they could pretty easily gain unauthorized access to your site.  an idea might be to use SSL if you're really worried about security (has more features than just hiding username and password)

Answer (score 1):

In your `checkLogin.php` page, you're storing the username in `$_SESSION['myusername']` and in your `login_success.php` page, you're checking to see if `$_SESSION['Username']` exists.  Change one or the other so they're both the same, and this should fix your problem.